# How to write an array method that Returns a double array that has as its elements a sliding average of the parameter array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, methods, double

I'm working on a project where I need to create a method where the parameter is a non-null `double[]` with at least 3 elements in it.

The result needs to have the first and last elements of the new array are the same as the average of the first two and last two elements of the parameter array, respectively, and For the other elements of the new array, the element at index `i`, is equal to the average of elements from the parameter array at indices `i-1`, `i`, and `i+1`.

I also need to make sure that the array parameter isn't changed.

An example of this is Calling `smoothArray([0.0, 0.2, 0.7, 0.2])` should return a new array `[0.1, 0.3, 0.3666...,0.45]`. You may see differences in your numerical values based on representational error of double numbers.

I'm at a complete loss for this, and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You can relate your logic with this C++ code given below:

```
double newarr[len];
newarr[0] = (arr[0] + arr[1]) / 2;
newarr[len - 1] = (arr[len-1] + arr[len-2]) / 2;
for (int i = 1; i < len - 1; i++)
{
    newarr[i] = (arr[i - 1] + arr[i] + arr[i + 1]) / 3;
}
```